# Embedding / rendering problems loading a server side generated SVG asynchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I am trying to override some JavaScript code to optimize an existing solution of which I do not have access to the original source code. It is a Liferay based portal with some portlets that render an SVG image. The SVG is used as a graphical navigation element which can be used to drill down into a technical service model. The loading and refreshing of the SVG image can be slow because of the way it has been implemented. The SVG disappears for a couple of seconds because the refresh actually does 2 requests to the webserver. At first the complete object tag is regenerated server side and re-inserted in the dom. 
The response of the first request looks like this:

```
<div><object type="image/svg+xml" data="generateSvg.svg” width="100" height="300" name="svgId"> <param name="wmode" value="transparent"></object></div>
```

The actual request of the SVG starts by the time the first response text is inserted into the DOM and the original object tag is removed. Because the SVG images can get quite complex and some general slowness of the software the SVG disappears and returns by the time it is received and rendered by the web-browser. 
I would like to skip the first step and make sure the image does not “blink” by refreshing the SVG asynchronously. Using jQuery I am able to override the original JavaScript code and get the url of the SVG and do a jQuery ajax request. I am also able to insert the results in the DOM but when I insert it as an inline SVG the image is rendered different then when it is embedded in an object tag. 
Some parts of svg content elements are cut off and this does not happen when the SVG is added as an object tag with an external url.

I either would like to embed the SVG in an object tag and load its url asynchronously or find a fix for the rendering problems of the inline SVG. I cannot change the SVG code since it is part of the existing software. I there a way to add the asynchronous loaded data to an object tag without adding the url to the data attribute?

My javascript for adding the SVG looks like this:

```
indentifier.loadSvg = (function(){
    if(this.svgUrl){                        
        $.ajax({
            url: this.svgUrl,
            //enclose the right div in which the svg should be loaded as a context
            context: $('#_layout_WAR_Portlets_INSTANCE_' + this.portalId + '_plugin'),
            dataType: 'xml'
            }).done(function(svgDoc) {
                //construct an svg node and add it to the DOM
                var svgNode = $('svg', svgDoc);
                var docNode = document.adoptNode(svgNode[0]);
                $(docNode).attr('width', '100%').attr('height', '300');
                this.html(docNode);
            });

    }
});
```

Comment: The rendering problems only occur on the SVG elements that have a custom bind namespace that is used to resize elements based on the length of their name or de number of sub-elements inside a bounding box. When the content is added async the elements appear imidiately while the elements seem to be rendered (first the bounding box and later the background color appears) when added trough an object tag with a data attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's possible inside an object tag but an Iframe should do the trick.
You could try creating a new Object tag with javascript, loading the svg and replacing the old object with the new one. 
It would look something like this:

```
var datasrc = "#";

// Create new object tag
var newobj = jQuery('<obj>', {
    id: 'newobject',
    data: datasrc,
    type: 'image/svg+xml'
});
    // Set parameters
    jQuery('<param />', {
        name: 'src',
        value: datasrc
    }).appendTo('#newobj');
    jQuery('<param />', {
        name: 'wmode',
        value: 'transparent'
    }).appendTo('#newobj');

// Dynamically load content and replace when done
newobj.load(datasrc,function(){
    $('#objectwrapper').empty();
    newobj.appendTo('#objectwrapper');
    alert("succes"); // Just to check if this works!
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cfERU/9/

The alert wil fire twice, I believe this is a JSFiddle thing.

Comment: Adding the data attribute to the object tag reintroduces the refresh problem but the SVG is displayed correctly. Adding the object tag without the data attribute renders the SVG but again with the rendering problems as seen before and it apears that we just added an object tag to an inline SVG element.